# When switching to tty, bluetooth headset is being disconnected

Tags: fedora, gnome, bluetooth, wayland

I have a bluetooth headset connected to my computer. Whenever I switch to a different `tty` (virtual terminal), it disconnects and as a result, the audio playback stops. I want this behaviour to change so that I can continue hearing music while working on virtual terminal. How do I do that?

Steps:

1. in GNOME/Wayland session, have a bluetooth headset connected
2. start any audio playback (e.g. opening a `.mp3` file using totem a.k.a. Videos)
3. switch to a different `tty`, e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>
4. try to listen to audio

What happens:
My headset says “bluetooth disconnected”. Audio playback stops. This is independent from the application which plays audio (music players, web browsers, …)

What do I expect to happen:
My headset should stay connected. Audio playback should continue.

I'm using Fedora 34 with GNOME/Wayland.

Comment: I would say that's not possible. When you switch to a tty, you change the active environment completely, so the DE is "on hold" until you switch to it again. So it's not a bluetooth problem. You can try this: play some music from an application, switch to the tty, wait a couple of seconds, then switch to the DE. The music didn't keep playing.

Comment: That's true: The music stops playing when I switch to `tty`.